# How to let a user know of a clickable area

Tags: android, tables, lists, column-headers

I'm creating an application (Android for starters) which will have a list. I want to create a special column headers that the user can press on (press on the entire column header section; not on each header individually) so he can change some settings regarding the header section.

What is the best way to let a user know that an area you wouldn't normally click (like column headers) is indeed clickable?

Answer (score 1):

If the element is clickable, make it noticeable and get rid of any uncertainty about the [**affordance**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/24/affordance-most-underrated-word-in-web-design/) of the given element.

In order to achieve this, you can try different options:

- **use a [floating button action](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) as trigger:** this is the Google Material approach, so it's meant for Android, and it visually helps the user to clearly understand what is a header and what is an action
- **make your element look like a button:** while you mention a header, is there a reason this header can't have a "button like" aspect? This will indeed take care of the mentioned uncertainty, bar none
- **add iconography to support the expected affordance:** you can simply add an icon to let the user know the element has a supplemental action

Either way, you should be very careful about this element's behavior. This is a clear indication of a common mistake: *confusing content with actions*. If this is a header, then *it should be a header and nothing else*. If it's an action, then make it an action. **Content** is a semantic description of your site's ... well, content. **Actions** indicates the particular element will perform some... well, action, and requires user response (touch, click, swipe and such).

Just remember one thing: the clearer and unmistakable the element's affordance is, the better. So, just make a header a header, and if you need any user interaction, add any supplemental action you need for that purpose

## Additional content

Make sure to take a look to this article about [**Clickable Elements**](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/), it has several tips, *do's* and *dont's* about this particular subject